# Subprocess.check_call() does not open a window

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a piece of code which uses `subprocess.check_call()` to call a Python script. It runs all good, however, it does not show the GUI window that the script shows when it runs standalone. Somehow `subprocess.check_call()` does not respect any GUI threads I guess.

Here are the two lines that are relevant:

```
command = [self.python3, self.execution_dir + '/' + "script.py", "-i" + self.received_img_path]
subprocess.check_call(command, env={'PYTHONPATH': local_pythonpath })
```

Is there a way to make the function also open the GUI windows? Or is there another function for that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.check_call()` is not supposed to spawn a separate GUI window (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)). To spawn a GUI window you need to explicitly run a program with a GUI like `gnome-terminal` and use its arguments to control the program. So e.g.

```
import subprocess
command = [self.python3, self.execution_dir + '/' + "script.py", "-i" + self.received_img_path]
subprocess.check_call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', ' '.join(command)],
                      env={'PYTHONPATH': local_pythonpath })
```

will spawn a GUI terminal and run your command.

Comment: Also running Python as a subprocess from Python doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution. `import` the code you want and run it in the current process.

Comment: @tripleee You can't do that if you use Python2 and want to execute a Python3 code.

Comment: @Frank Podborski Thank you. However that throws an error: `# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
# Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: 
('Exception caught: %s', CalledProcessError())`

Comment: If you are trying to run this from a `cron` job or similar, that's a different can of worms. This should work at the prompt within a running desktop session where `DISPLAY` is properly set.

Comment: I am using typical gnome terminal, and the output of `echo $DISPLAY` is `:1`. EDIT: Okay, the problem was `sudo`. Fixed it. Works.